# Need regex for perfect match [a-z0-9]

Tags: regex

I need to select only `dsadcczs` by regex and it must be in 1 line at once

```
('dsadcczs', 'https://link.com/cxsdsdas.php', 'wells', '2020-08-24 06:02:17', '::1', 0)
```

`dsadcczs` can be any word i need `[a-z0-9]` in this.

I already tried `(?:^|\W)[a-z0-9](?:$|\W)` but not work

Comment: Do you want to only match the first element of the list?

Comment: Only match the word before the 1st comma?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex flavor supports lookbehind, you can use:

```
(?<=\(')[^']+
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/bq4VCX/1)

Comment: Wow man its works like champ..this is what exactly what i wants.Thanks

Comment: @MăȼkĦøṩsąiɳ: You're welcome, glad it helps.